# view file output while debugging

Tags: c, debugging, file

The problem with redirecting the output to a file in debug mode is that I can not view the content of file (size is zero) until the program finish. With this usages:

```
FILE *f;
f = fopen("log.txt", "w");
fprintf(f, "cycle =%d\n", c);
```

while I am debugging, I want to view the track "cycle =" in the file right after stepping out "fprintf" statement.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Have you considered just printing the output to a global buffer in your program and viewing the buffer's contents right in the debugger? This works even better if you have your own logging function, since you can switch between logging to a memory buffer and logging to a logfile with some preprocessor conditionals (i.e. #ifdef DEBUG).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to put `fflush(f);` after `fprintf()` function call, which will make the data be written immediately.

Comment: what is the difference with fsync?

Comment: the content of output file is overwritten every time after fflsush(f). I mean I can not see "cycle =1" "cycle =2". Only I see "cycle =2". any idea?

Comment: Is it possible that you reopen the file before you printing cycles count? If it is the case you should open the file in the append mode `fopen("log.txt", "a+");`

Answer (score 2):

While I don't see it in C99, setlinebuf() is a function that has been available in any C I needed it in. Calling setlinebuf() *before the first output to the file* forces each line to go out immediately using "line buffering".

```
f = fopen("log.txt", "w");
if ( !f )
   oops();
if ( debugging_mode )
    setlinebuf( f );
```

No need for individual calls to fflush(), fsync(), etc.

Beware this slows down programs doing lots of output so reserving it for debugging mode can be important for performance of some programs.

If you don't have setlinebuf(), try the following, which is C99:

```
   setvbuf(f, (char *)NULL, _IOLBF, 0);
```

Comment: +1 for `setvbuf()` with `_IOLBF` (which is probably the best way to do it), though I'd recommend the use of BUFSIZ instead of 0 for the last parameter.  That allows the system to buffer a line at time in a buffer it allocates.

Answer (score 0):

Use `fsync`:

```
FILE *f;
f = fopen("log.txt", "w");
fprintf(f, "cycle =%d\n", c);
fsync(f);
```

Comment: the content of output file is overwritten every time after fflsush(f). I mean I can not see "cycle =1" "cycle =2". Only I see "cycle =2". any idea?

Comment: If you want different executions to add to the end of the log file you need to open in append mode: fopen("log.txt", "a"). If several programs can write to the log file at the same time not only is append mode important, each write must end with a "\n", the lines can not be long, and line buffering must be set (see my answer for details) or the output of the different programs can be interleaved in the log file.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `fflush(f)` after your call fprintf should ensure that the output is visible to other programs (although not necessarily written to disk).

If this is code that you can't or would rather not modify, and you're debugging with GDB, you can get the debugger to call fflush for you with `call fflush(f)`.

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps - [How to monitor log files in real-time?](http://codereflect.com/2011/07/29/tools-how-to-monitor-log-files-in-real-time/)